# Initiate a PHP class where class name is a variable

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx

I need some help with an error I have not encountered before and can't seem to find anywhere.

In a PHP mvc framework (just from a tutorial) I have the following:

```
// Initiate the class
$className = 'Controller_' . ucfirst($controller);
if (class_exists($className)) {
 $controller = new $className($this->registry);
}
```

$className is showing the correct class name (case is also correct). But when I run it I get this in the apache error log (no php error)

```
[Wed Mar 31 10:34:12 2010] [notice] child pid 987 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Process id is different on every call. I am running PHP 5.3.0 on os x 10.6. This site seems to work on 5.2.11 on another Mac. Not really sure where to go next to debug it. I guess it could be an apache setting as much as a php bug or a problem with the code... any suggestions on where to look next?

The error does not appear on commenting out that code. I also have about 15 other php sites running with no problems. Including others using the same base mvc framework

Comment: Since it's a segfault there doesn't have to be something wrong with the script but definitely with the php build. A script should never be able to crahs the php instance (so hard that the os has to terminate the process).

Comment: Do you get the segfault if you comment out that line of code?  (i.e. is it definitely these 4 lines of code causing the problem?)

Comment: I'd assume this to be caused either by faulty hardware or by any of the modules loaded in Apache. Voting to move to serverfault.

Comment: Why has a programming question been migrated away from SO?

Comment: Because the error is not from the code, but from the php built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember having the exact same issue. If I remember correctly the problem was recursive instantiation, i.e. PHP ran out of memory, which caused the segmentation fault. Check that the instantiation of $className does not go around in circles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Initiate the class
$className = 'Controller_' . ucfirst($controller);
if (class_exists($className)) {
     // construct the code string and evaluate it.
     $code='$controller = new ' . $className . '($this->registry);';
     eval($code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is from your own mac. If you did try the website from another computer and did not get the error, then that mean you'll need to reinstall you php package. Something went wrong at some time with your php built (maybe an update, or an link destroyed because of new installation...)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curly braces around your class name variable.  See below in the $controller assignment line.

```
$className = 'Controller_' . ucfirst($controller);
if (class_exists($className)) {
 $controller = new ${$className}($this->registry);
}
```